# Why don't the Autobots use their lasers in combat?

Tags: plot-explanation, transformers, dark-of-the-moon

In *Transformers: Dark Of The Moon*, there is a scene where the Autobots find Sentinal on the crashed ship on the moon. They then proceed to use their lasers to cut through the ship's metal hull. Presumably the ship was made from the same material ([Transformium](https://transformers.fandom.com/wiki/Transformium)) that all of the transformers are made of.

**My Question:**
Given that the Decepticons are made up of the same material as the spaceship, and the Autobots' lasers can cut through that with ease, why do the Autobots not use their lasers in combat?

Comment: This would be difficult to answer since there is no continuity and the movies make absolute nonsense. You could ask the same question about why Prime uses a sword instead of his gun part 4. The answer is probably "just because".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do Transformers die?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/101568/how-do-transformers-die)

Comment: I voted this question as duplicate, because the explanation is the same: inconsistent scripts in the series.

Comment: @Luciano The meta discussion you started is appreciated and it's understandable you're fed up with questions seeking explanations for stuff that's not to be explained. But...at the same time we're not really closing questions as duplicates of *entirely unrelated* questions just because the answer is "it's Michael Bay, bro!" If you want to solve some apparent problem with plot-inconsistencies, I'm afraid you have to put a little more effort in than picking some random question as a duplicate target.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson it was not a random question. it just happens that both movies are Michael Bay's _and_ the same franchise _and_ have inconsistent plots...

Comment: ...and are asking entirely different questions about entirely different story elements.